# C++ program to copy a file into another

Tags: xcode7

I have the following section of code. Am using XCode. Where should i place the source.txt and target.txt so as to be accessible?

```
std::ifstream fin("source.txt");
std::ofstream fout("target.txt");
fout<<fin.rdbuf(); //sends the text string to the file "target.txt"

system("pause"); 
return 0;
```

Comment: unless you're doing a dir change elsewhere, usually the "default" working directory for any code is the same directory the executable is run from.

Comment: I have typed the following code and the SCopy.txt and SCopy2.txt are on the same directory. When i run main.cpp it does nothing but only displaying "Build succeeded" what could be the problem?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream in("SCopy.txt");
    ofstream out("SCopy2.txt");
    string S;
    while(getline(in,S));
    out<<S<<"\n";
    
}